# how to send data from function using onclick in form using type submit

Tags: javascript, node.js

how to send newdata from function in onclick in form using type=submit so that i can access this data in my post route on server side.

```
    <form action="/cart"   method="POST" >
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"  
         onclick="myfunction('<%= i %>')" name="submit"    value="Add to my Cart" >
                 </form>

    <script  >


        function myfunction(i) {

          console.log(i);
          var n = document.images.item(i).src;
          console.log(n)
          var el = document.querySelectorAll("#demo");
          console.log(el[i].innerText)
          var newdata={img :n ,title:el[i].innerText}
          return(newdata)

        }
          </script>
```

I want to access newdata here as soon as i click submit my data from myfunction(i) should be rendered here .How to do that ?.

```
app.post("/cart",function(req,res){
     console.log(req)
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add this to the end of `myfunction`:

```
fetch("/cart", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(newdata)
}.then(function(response) {
  // Handle Response
});
```

2) Install the npm module `body-parser`:

```sh
npm install body-parser
```

3) Add this to the top of your file:

```
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
```

and this right after you define `app`:

```
app.use(bodyparser.json());
```

4) The data you sent over can now be accessed with `req.body`:

```
app.post("/cart", function(req, res) {
  console.log(res.body); // should be equal to newdata
});
```

Comment: I am getting value of submit button i.e { submit: 'Add to my Cart' }  as an output .On the other hand i want (newdata) as an output in my console on server side.

Comment: How are you getting the value of the submit button?

Comment: It is by default present in my req.body because of value attribute . It is is not modifying body .I did exactly what you told .

Comment: also it is showing me this as an error TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}.then is not a function